# Using 2x classes to select and toggle a third with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following jQuery to select and toggle a class on buttons, that i am selecting using two other classes. Why does the selector not complain, but does not change the classes? I have a [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/TheRealPapa/635v4cyc/).

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.ajax-multi-btn', function(event) {
  if ($(this).hasClass('ly')) {
    $('button.ajax-multi-btn.ty').removeClass('secondary-menu-active');
    $('button.ajax-multi-btn.ly').addClass('secondary-menu-active');
  } else {
    $('button.ajax-multi-btn.ty').addClass('secondary-menu-active');
    $('button.ajax-multi-btn.ly').removeClass('secondary-menu-active');
  }

});
```

I have the following HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn ajax-multi-btn ty secondary-menu-active">TY</button>

<button type="button" class="btn ajax-multi-btn ly">LY</button>
```

Comment: where is the button `button.ajax-single-btn`

Comment: in your fiddle, your code to remove/add targets `button.ajax-multi-btn.xy` but the buttons have class `ajax-single-btn` not `ajax-multi-btn` - where as here it's the other way around

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed your script on fiddle to work, you just have an error on the class you were using on the remove and add class functions.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button.ajax-single-btn', function(event) {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('ly')) {
    $('button.ajax-single-btn.ty').removeClass('secondary-menu-active');
    $('button.ajax-single-btn.ly').addClass('secondary-menu-active');    
    alert('ly');
  } else {
    $('button.ajax-single-btn.ty').addClass('secondary-menu-active');
    $('button.ajax-single-btn.ly').removeClass('secondary-menu-active');
    alert('ty');
 }
});
```

```css
.secondary-menu-active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn ajax-single-btn ty secondary-menu-active">
  TY
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn ajax-single-btn ly">
  LY
</button>
```

Comment: Been a long night and day so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your FIDDLE the html markup does not have the buttons with class `ajax-multi-btn` so the ones in your script won't work because it was selecting buttons that does not exist. Why not update your script to use the right classes?

see demo:

```js
$(document).on('click', 'button.ajax-single-btn', function(event) {


  if (!$(this).hasClass('ly')) {

    $('button.ajax-single-btn.ty').removeClass('secondary-menu-active');
    $('button.ajax-single-btn.ly').addClass('secondary-menu-active');
    
    alert('ly');

  } else {

    $('button.ajax-single-btn.ty').addClass('secondary-menu-active');
    $('button.ajax-single-btn.ly').removeClass('secondary-menu-active');

    alert('ty');

}

});
```

```css
.secondary-menu-active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn ajax-single-btn ty secondary-menu-active">
  TY
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn ajax-single-btn ly">
  LY
</button>
```